# How to change checkbox label text when toggling check on bootstrap styled button group

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the label text for a [bootstrap styled button group checkbox](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons), but once changed, it isn't possible to change the text again. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/11/))

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group form-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="lblfilter-green" for="filter-green" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-green"/>
        On
    </label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#lblfilter-green').on('click', function (e) {
    var value = $('#filter-green').is(':checked');                

    if (value) {    
        $('#lblfilter-green').text("Off");
    } else {
        $('#lblfilter-green').text("On");
    }
});
```

Note - I'm unsure if it matters if you use change or click event and that I'm only doing the green button as an example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my solution for your problem:

I added a span for the text content like:

```
    <label id="lblfilter-green" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-green" /><span>Off</span>
    </label>
```

Then i altert you jquery to:

```
    $('label').click(function () {
        var checked = $('input', this).is(':checked');
        $('span', this).text(checked ? 'Off' : 'On');
    });
```

This provides a dynamic way to change the text and you dont have to care about ID's

[Full Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/16/)

Comment: Like the idea of using span, but I can't use the ternary operator as there are other things in the real code.

Comment: So then give the button groub an ID and query like $('#myButtonGrb label)... Then you should be fine!!

Answer (score 2):

After much investigation and not coming up with anything useful, I turned off the bootstrap styling and found that the check box element disappeared after you changed the text - I guess changing the label text replaces the check box element (not sure if this is a bug or by design, but its a little messy). But I solved it by adding the check box element back in explicitly: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/5/))

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group form-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="lblfilter-green" for="filter-green" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-green">
        On
    </label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#lblfilter-green').on('click', function (e) {
    var value = $('#filter-green').is(':checked');                

    if (value) {                    
        $('#lblfilter-green').html("<input type='checkbox' id='filter-green' /> Off");
    } else {
        $('#lblfilter-green').html("<input type='checkbox' id='filter-green' /> On");
    }
});
```

Note - it doesn't seem to matter if I set checked on the element explicitly ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/12/)):

```
$('#lblfilter-green').html("<input type='checkbox' id='filter-green' 'checked' /> On");
```

I'm unsure why, but assume bootstrap is doing something here as if you turn bootstap off, it becomes unreliable (and only works if you click the label not the check box due to the way the event is hooked up).

Comment: Why the -1? I put this answer to show how I solved it (though I have accepted a better one) in the hope to help people in future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure bootstrap solution without JavaScript using a button toggle nested inside a collapse toggle.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".check-box-label">
  <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
      <label class="check-box-label collapse show active" style="transition:none;">Checked</label>
      <label class="check-box-label collapse" style="transition:none;">Unchecked</label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The transition is a little twitchy but I'm sure that can be tweaked with some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code -

```
<div class="btn-group form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="lblfilter-green" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-green" />Off</label>
    <label id="filter-amber" class="btn btn-warning">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-amber" />Off</label>
    <label id="filter-red" class="btn btn-danger">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-red" />Off</label>
</div>
```

jQuery Code -

```
    $(document).on('click', '#lblfilter-green', function (e) {
        var value = $('#filter-green').is(':checked');                

        if (value ==false) {        
            $(this).html("<input type='checkbox' id='filter-green'>On");
        } else {

            $(this).html("<input type='checkbox' id='filter-green'>Off");
        }
    });
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/yhdzuakb/

Though I wonder the HTML structure of your code is like below.

```
<label id="lblfilter-green" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-green">Off</label>   //Input close tag is not there.
```

I kept your code the same and changed just On/off text based on unchecked/checked events. I think this is what your requirement was.

Comment: just missed the close tag by mistake, it seems to work either way, have corrected it.

Comment: the missing input close tag comes from the bootstrap example page

Answer (score 0):

Question: How can I change the label text without removing the checkbox?

HTML Code:

```html
<label class="optional" for="checkout_offer_opt_in">
     <input class="optional" type="checkbox"name="checkout_offer[opt_in]" id="checkout_offer_opt_in">
     You can unsubscribe anytime
</label>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var email_list_text = $('label[for=checkout_offer_opt_in]');
email_list_text .html(email_list_text .find('input'));
$(email_list_text ).append("By buying this product you agree to automatically");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can    be    done    like    this

```
var $labelControl = $("#lblfilter-green");

$labelControl.find("input").get(0).nextSibling.remove();

$labelControl.append("Off");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).